# replace one icon with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 icons in a wrapper what I want to achieve is when hover on the icon one of the icons hide and the other one shows. Something to note is the wrappers are getting loaded dynamically so I need to access them through `document`. Also I'm trying to use `this` because I only want the hovered element to change. How can I achieve this? I wrote a rough code below. Thanks in advance

```js
var fa_regular;
var fa_solid;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.wrapper .fa-regular', function() {
  fa_regular = $(this)
  $(fa_regular).css('display', 'none')
  $(fa_solid).css('display', 'flex')
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.wrapper .fa-solid', function() {
  fa_solid = $(this)
  $(fa_regular).css('display', 'flex')
  $(fa_solid).css('display', 'none')
});
```

```css
.wrapper i {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .fa-regular {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .fa-solid {
  display: none;
  color: rgb(224, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done through CSS & it's a lot cleaner, js leads to stuttering imo. Just combine the images into one, make it wide + side-by-side. Default css is `#img{ object-fit:none; object-position: 0 0; height: 40px; width: 60px;}` and hover: `#img:hover{ object-position: -65px 0 }` which sorta moves the picture over. Height/Width/Position will need to be tinkered with. Hope this helps

Comment: @Nealium the icons are not images they are custom fonts by font awesome.

Comment: @Nealium plus how would you target specific icons if it is with css?

Comment: Bummer! Try changing your: `$(fa_regular)` + `$(fa_solid)` to `$(this).parent().find('.fa-regular')` + `$(this).parent().find('.fa-solid')` (go up to wrapper, find x inside) ..technically you only need to change the one that isn't `fa_type = $(this)`

Comment: You'd just use Class or IDs to target specific icons. If I said `.text:hover{ color: red; }` when I hover over a .text element it would only make the one I'm hovering over red

Comment: @Nealium Yeah targeting the parent then looking for the class is a nice solution. Thanks for your help. You can add an answer below then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$obj -> parent.wrapper -> find inside

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.wrapper .fa-regular', function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none')
    $(this).parent().find('.fa_solid').css('display', 'flex')
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.wrapper .fa-solid', function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none')
    $(this).parent().find('.fa_solid').css('display', 'flex')
});
```